# Terminal: select all programmatically

Tags: terminal, xfce4-terminal

Assuming I have selected all in terminal (either w/ Ctr-Shf-A or o/wise), I can programmatically write the selection to a file w/ e.g. `xsel`. But is there a program, command or similar for select all? I know this can be done by sending keypresses (e.g. w/ `xbindkeys`), which is roundabout and clumsy. **Is there an easier way — to select all or (even better) a programmatic way to capture console buffer or output to a file?** `tee` and `script` mangle the dynamic output of the program I'm trying to capture and redirection doesn't suit me, as I want the output on the screen as well. I [read](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/vcs.4.html) that `cat`-ing my virtual terminal (`sudo cat /dev/vcs7` — `screendump` uses this) should work but no — e.g. `ls` displays something but following it w/ `sudo cat /dev/vcs7` shows nothing

Comment: You can use GNU screen hardcopy feature but you have to start it first.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk you mean [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4807474/copying-the-gnu-screen-scrollback-buffer-to-a-file-extended-hardcopy/6604296#6604296)? Can I do it programmatically, w/out Ctr-A, etc?

Comment: Yes: `screen -X hardcopy /tmp/HERE`

Comment: You should make this into an answer. (I haven't screen installed but could do it)

Answer (score 3):

You could use GNU screen *hardcopy* feature:

```
screen -X hardcopy /tmp/HERE
```